# Are there any good online resources for Mongolian myths in English?

Tags: source-request, mongolian-shamanism

I want to learn more about Mongolian mythology but am having trouble finding texts in English (I only speak English).

Answer (score 1):

The only English source I have lying around here is; "Mongol creation stories: man, Mongol tribes, the natural world, and Mongol deities, by Nassen-Bayer and Kevin Stuart. It's not a big book (only 12 pages or so) and I have [**found an online source**](http://ccbs.ntu.edu.tw/FULLTEXT/JR-EPT/stuart1.htm) where you can read it for free, I will also include the text in my answer.

### THE ORIGIN OF MAN, THE MONGOLS, AND MONGOL TRIBES

> In one tale the creation of the world is attributed to a lama named
> Udan:
> Long ago there lived a lama named Udan who created everything
> in the world. When he was five hundred years old, heaven, earth,
> and everything else had yet to appear. When he reached the age
> of one thousand Udan divided heaven and earth into separate
> entities,
> creating a nine-story heaven, a nine-story earth, and nine rivers.
> Finally the lama made a man and a woman out of clay. They
> married and had children, and the entire human race descends
> from them. (BAJAR 1988, 27)
> The foreign influence of Lamaism is at work here. The word lama, for
> example, was probably added to the tale after the spread of Buddhism
> to Mongol regions. It should be noted, however, that many Buddhists
> and Lamaists consider the Buddha to have been the creator of the
> world, so that this account is somewhat at odds with this Buddhist
> belief.

**Why Man Has No Hair**

> Another creation story, "Why Man Has No Hair," explains why man is
> not hirsute and also hints at why he became mortal. The creator god
> in this story is Burqan Tenger.
> Long long ago God descended to earth and made a man and a
> woman out of clay. Before returning to heaven to get some holy
> water with the power to animate anything, he ordered his dog and
> cat to protect the clay people from the devil. After God ascended
> to heaven, the devil came to harm the people. The dog and the
> cat protected them, though, thwarting the devil's plan. Finally,
> the devil deceived them by giving a piece of meat to the dog and
> a bowl of milk to the cat. While the dog ate the flesh and the cat
> lapped the milk, the devil urinated on the people and fled.
> When God returned with the holy water and discovered what
> had happened, he was enraged. Scolding the dog and cat for
> neglecting their duty, he forced the cat to lick the hair off the
> bodies
> of the people whom the devil had defiled (God created humans
> with hair all over their bodies). The cat licked off the hair
> everywhere
> except their heads, armpits, and crotches, since the former
> had not been dirtied and the latter two were hard for the cat to
> reach. God then put the hair that had been licked away by the
> cat onto the body of the dog, so that humans are now naked and
> dogs have hair. The Mongol saying that the tongue of the cat
> and the hair of the dog are dirty has its origin here. Man and
> woman, who were animated by drinking the holy water, should
> have been immortal but became mortal instead because of their
> defilement by the devil. (GADAMBA and CERENSODNOM 1984, 742)
> In this account, everything made by Burqan Tenger has both positive
> and negative aspects. There is duality in all that is created:
> beauty is tempered by ugliness, joy with suffering.
> The following account offers an explanation for why the Chinese
> population is so much larger than the Mongolian:
> God made many people from clay and placed some in the north and
> some in the south. After many years God, thinking that man
> must have multiplied, came down to take a look. When he found
> that the population had not increased, he recalled that he had made
> males but no females. He therefore put many hens in the south
> and seven ewes in the north. The men and hens of the south are
> the ancestors of the Chinese. Seven men in the north received the
> seven ewes. One of the men, out of greed, killed his sheep to eat
> at once. But after seven days the remaining ewes turned into
> beautiful girls and married the men. These are the ancestors of
> the Mongols. The Mongols' population growth is very slow because
> they are descended from ewes, and the Chinese multiply
> rapidly because they are descended from hens. (MANDAQU 1981,
> 105)
> This tale probably springs from nomadic culture, since the nomadic
> Mongols commonly keep sheep but not chickens, which are raised by
> farmers and are used in the story to symbolize the Han Chinese.

**The origin of the Mongolian tribes**

> There are at least two popular accounts concerning the origin of the
> Mongolian tribes, one involving the Dorbed tribe and the other the
> Buryat tribe.
> Long long ago the Dorbed tribe lived near Nidu Mountain. The
> mountain towered so tall that its snow-covered top was perpetually
> lost in clouds. A spring of water gushed forth and flowed into a
> lake near the mountaintop. The lake was surrounded by forests.
> One day a young hunter went up the mountain and reached
> the lake. There, to his great astonishment, he heard the sound of
> laughing voices. Curious, the young hunter approached and
> found four goddesses playing and dancing. He watched them,
> spellbound, as they frolicked in the lake one moment and rested
> in the sky the next. Returning to his senses, the hunter hurriedly
> descended the mountain to his home. Taking his catch-pole, he
> returned to the lake and hid behind a bush. As the unsuspecting
> goddesses played he tossed his pole and caught one. The other
> goddesses flew up into the sky. The young hunter voiced his love
> to the goddess he had captured, and with great pleasure she accepted
> it.
> They led a happy life, but because goddesses cannot live long
> on earth she eventually returned to heaven. Once there, however,
> she realized that she was pregnant, for her body grew heavier and
> heavier. Flying down to the side of the lake, she gave birth to
> a boy. She made a cradle and hung it from a tree branch, then
> placed the baby boy inside. She then put some of her own milk
> into a pot and hung the pot from a branch above the cradle, all the
> while missing the young hunter. The goddess found a small yellow
> bird that lived in Tang[gamma]ud and had it perch in the tree to
> sing
> day and night and look after the baby. Having prepared everything,
> the goddess returned to heaven.
> At that time the Dorbed tribe, being without a good leader,
> asked a fortune-teller how to find one. The fortune-teller told
> them that if they looked in the bushes by the lake on Nidu Mountain
> they would surely discover what they sought. Delighted, the
> Dorbed expressed their appreciation to the fortune-teller and, on
> a good day, went up the mountain. There, drawn by the yellow
> bird's song, they found the baby. The Dorbed took the infant
> home, believing him to be from heaven and the one destined to
> be their future leader. The small yellow bird flew around the
> cradle, unwilling to leave, but at last was forced to fly away into
> the blue sky.
> When the boy grew up, he achieved great deeds and became
> an outstanding hero. He was the forefather of the present Dorbed
> tribe. (OBOR MONG[gamma]OL-YIN KELE UTQA JOQIJAL SUDULQU [gamma]AJAR 1963, 10)

> Many years ago, Bar[gamma]utai, hunting around Lake Baikal, found
> seven beautiful girls playing in the lake. Bar[gamma]utai silently
> approached
> the lake and stole the clothing one of the girls had removed
> and placed there. After swimming in the lake, the girls
> went to get their clothes as Bar[gamma]utai watched stealthily from
> behind
> a tree. All of the girls but the youngest, whose clothing had
> been stolen by Bar[gamma]utai, put on their clothes, became swans,
> and
> soared up into the sky. Bar[gamma]utai then grasped the sobbing
> girl.
> They married and had eleven children, but the woman was unable
> to reclaim her clothes from the hunter no matter how often she
> begged him. One day, the woman found her clothing and put
> it on. She then became a swan and flew away through the yurt
> skylight. The children were the Buryat's ancestors. (GADAMBA
> and CERENSODNOM 1984, 1023)

> The above two stories trace the origins of these two tribes to
> goddesses and hunters, both of which were venerated in ancient
> times. These two accounts likely originated in ancient times because
> of the role played by the swan and the yellow bird. Among ancient
> Mongol tribes the swan was a totem, and the Buryat and Bar[gamma]a
> tribes sacrificed to it (ZHAO 1988, 32).

### ON NATURAL PHENOMENA

> Some folklore accounts are concerned with the sun, moon, stars,
> wind, and earth. This suggests the interest the ancient Mongols had
> in the origins, transformation, and development of natural
> phenomena. Let us first examine accounts dealing with the earth.
> In ancient times, the earth was submerged in water and formed a
> boundless ocean. When the lord of the universe, Buddha Sakyamuni,
> was flying over the ocean to find a way to create the earth,
> he saw a frog swimming from north to south. Observing the
> golden-bodied frog, Buddha used his fingers to divine that the
> earth would be created on the back of the golden frog. Buddha
> unslung his bow and arrows and shot the golden frog's east side,
> turning the frog in a northerly direction. Fire gushed from its
> mouth and water spouted from its rump. Buddha threw golden
> sand on the frog, which became the earth where we now live. The
> part of the arrow protruding from the frog's east side became a
> forest, while the arrowhead that had passed through the frog to the
> west became a metal area. Because of the fire which gushed from
> the frog's mouth, the north became an area of fire. Because of the
> water spouting from the frog's rump, the south became a watery
> area. So our earth consists of the above five elements (fire, wood,
> water, metal, sand) and exists on the body of the frog. When the
> frog moves its legs or shakes its head, earthquakes result. (SECEN
> 1987, 119)

**how the world came to have form**

> In Mongol folklore there are also descriptions of how the world came
> to have form. A few examples: the edges of sky and earth came
> together in the way two pots are set against one another; there are
> ninety-nine golden columns holding apart the sky and earth; the
> world has three stories, the upper one being heaven where gods and
> goddesses live, the middle one being earth where man dwells, and the
> lower one being the place where man goes after death; heaven (sky)
> is the father and earth is the mother of man, animals, etc.
> Some scholars have argued that the ancient Mongols created simple
> stories because of a lack of a broad explanatory base of knowledge,
> while other scholars argue that they were longer and more
> complicated when initially created and subsequently lost various
> elements under the influence of Buddhism and other philosophies
> (SECEN 1987, 116).

> Other stories lost various parts in the process
> of being retold from generation to generation over a long historical
> period. The following are two brief examples dealing with the origin
> of the earth.
> In the beginning the world was covered with roiling gas. The
> temperature increased and dampness was generated from the
> warm gas, causing it to rain heavily. The world became a vast
> ocean, and at last dust and sand rose to cover the ocean surface and  become >earth.
>
> The primordial world was dark gas with no separation between
> earth and sky. After many years, brightness and darkness separated,
> with brightness becoming the sky and darkness becoming
> the earth. After many more years, fourty-four tenger (gods or
> buddhas) appeared in the east and fifty-five tenger appeared in
> the west, south, and north, and the Great Bear was taken as the
> standard. Thus there were ninety-nine tenger in heaven. At that
> time the earth was floating and had not stabilized, and there were
> neither animals nor vegetation. The tenger then created man and
> had them descend to earth to plant vegetation. At last the earth
> stabilized. (SECEN 1987, 120)
> From the foregoing we infer that ancient Mongolian thought saw the
> world as generated from dark gas. There were also explanations
> concerning the origin of wind, stars, the sun, and the moon. The
> following stories explain how the wind, Ursa Major, and the sun took
> form.
> There is an old woman in heaven who has a skin sack containing
> the wind. If she is angry, she opens her sack and the wind blows
> on earth. If she is furious, she opens the sack wider and wider
> and the wind becomes stronger. When she is in good spirits, she
> closes the sack and the wind stops. Thus, people shouldn't willfully
> offend the old woman. (ANONYMOUS 1984, 16)

> Long ago two brothers met a man as they set out hunting one
> morning. "What are you doing?" they asked him. The man
> answered, "I am waiting for a bird I just now shot to fall from
> the sky." When noon came, the bird dropped from the sky, impaled
> by an arrow. The three then became (sworn) brothers.
> They went on and met four persons in succession, the first a man
> who could hear any sound on earth and in heaven, the second a
> strong man who could pile mountains on top of each other, the
> third a runner who could catch antelopes, and the fourth a magician
> who could drink up the sea. These seven men became (sworn)
> brothers and defeated Magpie Khan by employing their skills.
> In the end they became Ursa Major. (GADAMBA and CERENSODNOM
> 1984, 735)

> Long ago an old man's cow gave birth to a calf, the front part of
> which resembled a man and the rear part of which resembled a
> cow. Its name was Ama-ca[gamma]an. The calf grew up and performed
> many good deeds on man's behalf and so went to heaven and met
> Ca[gamma]an (White) Khan. The khan told the calf, "You did many
> good deeds for man but they dealt with you in an ill manner. I
> struggle with the khan of the devils every day and am going to
> defeat him with the (fighting) style of bulls, so please aid me."
> In order to help the khan, Ama-ca[gamma]an disguised himself as a
> doctor,
> went to the palace of Devil Khan, and slew him. But the wife
> of Devil Khan, a mangrus (monster), realized what had happened
> and threw an iron scraper at Ama-ca[gamma]an's back as he was
> ascending
> to heaven. Am-ca[gamma]an was cut into seven pieces, and these
> pieces
> later became Ursa Major. (CERENSODNOM 1987, 40)

**Erkei-Mergen**

> Long long ago, seven suns rose in the sky so that the rivers and
> vegetation on earth dried up and men and animals had great
> difficulty
> surviving. At that time, there lived a famous archer named
> Erkei-Mergen. People went to his home and said, "Please shoot
> the suns in the sky and let us live in happiness."
> Erkei-Mergen was a brave, young, and proud man. He
> promised, "I want to shoot the seven suns using only seven arrows.
> If I can't accomplish this I will cut off my thumbs, never
> drink again, and live as an animal rather than as a man." The
> archer then began to shoot the suns from east to west. He shot
> down six, but while he was taking aim at the seventh a martin flew
> in front of the sun and was shot in the tail. From then on, the
> martin's tail has pointed in two different directions. The last sun
> was frightened of the archer and fled behind West Mountain.
> Angry at the martin, the archer decided to catch it using his fast
> horse, Qarcagai-Alag. The horse vowed, "If I can not catch the
> martin before dusk, you can cut off my four limbs and abandon
> me on the open steppe. I will not live as a horse any longer."
> But when dusk came, the horse had still not caught up with the
> martin. Erkei-Mergen, angry at his horse, cut off its front feet
> and left it on the steppe. The horse then became a jerboa,
> explaining
> why the jerboa's forelegs are shorter than its hind legs.
> This also explains why the martin always flies around those who
> ride horses with a chirping sound that translates as "Can you
> catch me?" Erkei-Mergen cut off his thumbs as he had promised
> and became a marmot, living in a dark hole. This explains why
> the marmot has only four claws. Marmots exit their holes in the
> morning and the evening because Erkei-Mergen still remembers
> his vow and desires to shoot the sun. And man does not eat the
> flesh of marmots because they evolved from Erkei-Mergen. From
> then on day and night have appeared in turn, since the sun flies
> behind West Mountain in fear [when the marmot exits its hole at
> dusk]. (GADAMBA and CERENSODNOM 1984, 735)
> God decided to punish the crafty monster, Raqu, but could not
> find him because Raqu had gone into hiding. God ordered the
> sun to find Raqu, but the sun could not do so. The moon found
> the place where Raqu was hiding and told God. Raqu was thus
> arrested and punished. From that time on, Raqu has been feuding
> with the sun and moon and always chases them. Solar and
> lunar eclipses occur just as the sun and moon are about to be
> caught.
> And when this happens, people shout and play musical instruments
> in order to frighten Raqu away. (SECEN 1987, 121)

### DEIFIED PERSONALITIES

> Deified personalities are human in appearance but
> divine in ability and power. The following three examples
> demonstrate this.
> Long ago a herdsman tending a herd of horses for a prince lost the
> animals. He couldn't find them no matter where he looked.
> Later, an old man named Jayaci, a horse breeder for the prince,
> told the herdsman, "Your lost horses ran to Altan-Bumbai Mountain
> and Erdeni-Bumbai Mountain located twenty kilometers southwest
> of here." The herdsman went there and found the horses just
> as Jayaci had said. Even when Jayaci was on the verge of death
> he still would not leave his horses. One day the prince asked him,
> "Why are you unwilling to leave?" Jayaci replied, "I hope that
> after I die, you will bury me between Altan-Bumbai and Erdeni-Bumbai
> mountains dressed in the clothing I wore when herding,
> and put my catch-pole beside my head. I also wish to be carried
> to my burial on my yellow horse." When the prince agreed to
> this, Jayaci stopped breathing. He was buried in accordance with
> his last request. After a few months had passed, some of the
> prince's herds of horses were stolen and driven to Altan-Bumbai
> and Erdeni-Bumbai at midnight. A pestilence then spread among
> the horses and they began to die. The prince went to Jayaci's
> grave, offered sacrifices to him, and said, "You have gone away
> and must be tired. The children in our home place are frightened
> of you. I suggest that you not leave here again. I will draw
> your image on a cattle skin and put it in my yurt to worship. This
> way you can see the horses and other domestic animals every day
> and you will feel very happy." Returning to his home, the prince
> drew an image of Jayaci on a cattle skin and worshipped him.
> From the following day horses were never stolen or taken ill again.
> And Jayaci, who had been seen at night, never appeared again.
> After a few months, Jayaci's wife also died. Soon after, some
> children became ill. People understood that this was because she
> missed children, since she had loved children very much during
> her lifetime. As soon as they drew her image on a clean white
> piece of felt and worshipped it the children recovered. Later,
> people worshipped Jayaci as the protecting deity of livestock and
> his wife as the protecting deity of children. When people came
> to use cloth, herdsmen moved the images of Jayaci and his wife
> from cattle skin and felt onto white cloth. (OBOR MONG[gamma]OL-YIN
> KELE UTQA JOQIJAL SUDULQU [gamma]AJAR 1963, 6)

**Qobolta**

> Qobolta stole a heavenly cow while in paradise and killed it to eat
> on
> a snowy mountain. The Lord of Heaven noticed this and sent
> an emissary to arrest Qobolta. Qobolta told the emissary, "The
> fact that I have stolen a heavenly cow is proof of the fact that I
> have been in heaven. I killed the cow in order to make a god
> image." The emissary replied, "I will not punish you if you
> really can make a god image," and returned to heaven. Qobolta
> cut the skin of the cattle into strips as wide as a finger, and
> wrapped
> each cattle bone with one of these strips. Next he distributed the
> images to everyone on earth, telling them, "This is the deity Bumal.
> If you sincerely believe in him, you will surely be healthy and
> happy all year and your domestic animals will breed and multiply."
> Qobolta was the first to believe in the deity. From that time on,
> Bumal became the embodiment of God for the Mongols. They
> always drew his image on cattle horns and put it outside their
> yurts to worship. (OBOR MONG[gamma]OL-YIN KELE UTQA JOQIJAL SUDULQU
> [gamma]AJAR 1963, 6)
> Many years ago, the brutal black Dragon King lived on the land
> and not in the sea. His constant attacks made him a dangerous
> enemy to man. At that time, there lived an old man who was only
> one span high but had a beard two spans long. He had a sack
> made from camel-neck skin, a spoon made of wild buck horn,
> and a billy goat. One day the old man set off to subdue Dragon
> King. On the way, the old man came to the sea. The sea asked,
> "Where are you going?" "I am going to vanquish the Dragon
> King," replied the old man. "How can you defeat him?" the sea
> inquired in an arrogant and contemptuous tone. The old man was
> very angry, and drew the entire sea into his spoon with a single
> dip, leaving the seabed dry. Putting the sea into his sack, he went
> on until he met a fox. "Where are you going?" asked the fox.
> "I am going to defeat Dragon King," answered the old man.
> "How can you do that?" the fox mockingly inquired. The old
> man was furious at this question, scooped up the fox, and put him
> in his sack. Next he met a wolf. "Where are you going?" asked
> the wolf. "I am going to defeat Dragon King," replied the old
> man. "How can you defeat Dragon King?" the wolf asked in a
> ridiculing tone. The old man was infuriated at the wolf, beat it
> with his spoon, and threw it too into his sack. He then continued
> his journey and arrived at the rear of Dragon King's palace.
> Climbing a hill behind the palace, he shouted, "I want to vanquish
> man's enemy, Dragon King." His voice was so loud that it shook
> the hill and Dragon King's heart. The proud Dragon King replied,
> "If you offend me so openly, I will release my ten thousand
> sheep to raise a dust that will settle upon and kill you." The ten
> thousand sheep then ran forth, but the old man set free the wolf
> from his sack. The sheep saw the wolf and fled, scattering in all
> directions. Then the Dragon King said, "I will send my two dogs
> to devour you," and set free Qasar and Qusar, his two dogs. The
> old man let the fox out of his sack. The fox fled from the dogs, and
> the dogs chased it far away. Dragon King began to be afraid, and
> ordered his ten thousand soldiers to attack the old man. But the old
> man wasn't worried and waited for the troops to approach. When
> they came near he opened his sack, and the sea poured out and
> rushed in with powerful waves upon Dragon King, his soldiers, and
> his palace. From then on Dragon King never lived on land but
> only in the sea. (OBOR MONG[gamma]OL-YIN KELE UTQA JOQIJAL SUDULQU
> [gamma]AJAR 1963, 3)
> Mongols living in the eastern part of Inner Mongolia made sacrifices
> to Jayaci and Bumal until the 1940s. Jayaci was venerated as the god
> who guarded livestock and Bumal as the protector of children. In
> general, it is thought that the two accounts related to Bumal and
> Jayaci are uninfluenced by Buddhism and arose from ancient Mongol
> society and culture.
> The brutal black Dragon King may be understood as the embodiment of
> natural catastrophe. In the defeat of the King, the Mongols express
> their desire to surmount the difficulties imposed by Nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look in:

[Grimms Märchen Anmerkungen (Bolte Polivka) V 212.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Grimms_M%C3%A4rchen_Anmerkungen_%28Bolte_Polivka%29_V_212.jpg)

This section is specifically about Mongolian "Fairy Tales."
It is written in German, but with a Google Translate and a bit of copy and paste, you can probably find a lot of good info. Some references are in English also. See below:

[image]

By the way, the Bolte book lists references of/from "Fairy Tales" from all over the planet (at least what was known as of 1932 anyway).